# How to handle the web Service in android applications

Tags: android, json

I have problem idk which web Service SDK to use in android application i have JSON and i want to get the data from it, i host the json on local server and i want to get the data from it for example this is my json object.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "time": 40,
    "srcLong": 35.909124,
    "srcLat": 31.973628,
    "destLong": 35.898258,
    "destLat": 31.985622,
    "subSites": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "loc1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "loc2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "loc3"
        }
    ]
}
```

is there any popular sdk with many samples on it i just want to get and post. and plz can you give me the website of the sdk to download it, i am afraid to download something else.

Comment: You can use Google Volley library, starting from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

Comment: You can also try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).